# How to hide a dynamically created element with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I want all the elements with id #text-field to be hidden (if the browser support JS, that's why it should be hidden with JS). But don't get it to work with elements created this way:

```
// Add post
$(document).on('click', 'a.add-post', function(event)
{
    // Create content based on a hidden item
    var newcontent = $('.type-post#post_id-hid-0').html();
    content = '<li class="type-post">' + newcontent + '</li>';

    // Place new content
    $('.posts-list > li.iteration-0').last().after(content);

    // Load necessary JS
    load_page();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And my **load_page()** function:

```
$(function()
{
    function load_page()
    {
        $('#text-field').hide();
    }

    load_page();
}
```

Comment: "I want all the elements with id #text-field to be hidden" IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Use a class instead of ID for repeated elements.

Comment: I suspected that you might point that out. I know about it and have thought about changing it. But it doesn't affect this problem. It works great to hide all elements with that ID on page load.

Comment: Browsers generally select the first matching element in case of duplicate ids. I doubt if _it doesn't affect this problem_.

Comment: My Bad!! That actually was the problem. I'm so sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class for text-field instead of an ID, ID's are unique for each element while a class can be used over again for this purpose.

Comment: Has nothing to do with this problem. Please focus on the problem instead.

Comment: Sorry, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight solution which doesn't require any JS to execute, and won't cause a 'jumpy' interface when it first loads and elements disappear in front of users eyes.

### CSS:

```
#text-field{display:hidden;}
```

### HTML:

```
<noscript>#text-field{display:block;}</noscript>
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you read my question again and you'll see that I made ​​an active choice to use JS. I know you can use CSS. But I want to use JS in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do two things:

```
function load_page(){ //<----put this in global scope
   $('.text-field').hide(); //<---hide it with class name
}
$(function(){
   load_page();
});
```

so now somewhere in your page you might have this `<input type='text' id='text-field' />` here you can change your elem's id to class this way:

```
<input type='text' class='text-field' />
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help if you can replace classname with whichever dynamic page related class you insert :

```
$(".classname[id='text-field']").hide();
```

or

```
$(".classname[id='text-field']").attr("style", "display:none");
```